# What is the tractability of the problem of traversing all the permutations of a set?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I wanted to implement a recursive algorithm to imitate nested for loops but with a count determined at run-time. For it I have to write a recursive algorithm that traverses all the permutations of a set.

I was curious about its tractability. I think that since permutations involve factorial function, the problem should be NP-Hard. I still want your insights about this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Iterating over all permutations is *O*(*n*!) which is about as bad as it gets. It's worse than polynomial, worse even than exponential. It's *not even NP-hard*, it's worse! Mathematically,

- *O*(*n*<sup>*c*</sup>) ⊂ *O*(*c*<sup>*n*</sup>) ⊂ *O*(*n*!).

Or, in English,

- polynomial < exponential < factorial.

For a problem to be NP its solution must be verifiable in polynomial time. The set of all permutations is of size *n*! ∈ *O*(*n*!) and cannot possibly be verified in polynomial time as verification requires one to iterate over the entire list.

To put it in perspective how bad this is, *O*(*n*!) is the complexity class of [bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort), a sorting algorithm where you sort a deck of cards by shuffling it and seeing if you got lucky.

Comment: @user58697 That's precisely what my answer says, no?

Comment: Sorry, got carried away as soon as I saw the NP.